# Put 2 arrays into a hash in perl

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I am trying to combine two arrays into a hash with one being the keys and one being the values. I have researched this, and found multiple ways to do it, but they dont implement correctly. My two arrays both have 348 values, but when I went to combine them, the hash only contains 9 key value pairs. I cannot figure out why this does not work.

```
my %hash;
@hash{@not_split_source_ips} = @source_lengths;

my $counter = @not_split_source_ips;
my $counter2 = @source_lengths;
print "$counter\n";
print "$counter2\n";

my $count = keys %hash;
print scalar(keys %hash);
```

`$counter` and `$counter2` both print out `348`, like they should, but `$count` only prints out 9. I tried using `List::MoreUtils qw( zip );` but got the same result.

When outputting the 9 lines that were together, those were from a random part of the file and not even the beginning.

```
@not_split_source_ips contains value like: 192.168.1.1.80
@source_lengths contains packet lengths: 0, 108, etc.
```

I also only included the print statements to check and show how it isn't working, I do not plan on using those in my actual project.

Comment: `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \%hash;` see the data, and you will find out why.

Comment: Like I included, it prints out 9 key value pairs (not 348) and those 9 are I would say numbers 150-158 (so from a random part of the source TCPDUMP file, not from the beginning or anything).

Comment: Then print your arrays and see what is in them. It is starting to sound like you might have duplicates in your arrays, which will reduce the number of keys, since hash keys are unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does @not_split_source_ips contain 348 *different* values, or 348 values that may have duplicates?

If there may be duplicates (which means you are actually looking for sums of packet lengths to that address), you probably want something like this:

```
my %hash;
%hash{$not_split_source_ips[$_]} += $source_lengths[$_] for 0 .. $#not_split_source_ips;
```

Comment: Thank both of you guys, that's it, it does have duplicates, your answer is much appreciated!